# Identify the porcessor type of a binary

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin

There are different ways to identify the processor type such as using IDA or `file`  command in Linux.  But sometimes the processor type is not detected by these tools. Besides I do not have the correct processor type of the binary. Is there any way to detect the correct type of processor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might try [cpu_rec](https://github.com/airbus-seclab/cpu_rec/), it claims to be able to identify a wide variety of architectures by analyzing the raw binary data.
According to [cpu_rec github repository](https://github.com/airbus-seclab/cpu_rec/blob/master/README.md#known-architectures-in-the-default-corpus) : Known architectures in the default corpus
[`68HC08`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freescale_68HC08)
[`68HC11`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freescale_68HC11)
[`8051`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MCS-51)
[`Alpha`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_Alpha)
[`ARcompact`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARC_(processor))
[`ARM64` `ARMeb` `ARMel` `ARMhf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture)
[`AVR`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR)
[`AxisCris`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ETRAX_CRIS)
[`Blackfin`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackfin)
[`Cell-SPU`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_(microprocessor))
[`CLIPPER`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_architecture)
[`CompactRISC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CompactRISC)
[`Cray`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cray)
[`Epiphany`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapteva)
[`FR-V`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FR-V_(microprocessor))
[`FR30`](http://www.fujitsu.com/downloads/MICRO/fma/pdfmcu/hm91101-cm71-10102-2e.pdf)
[`FT32`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTDI)
[`H8-300`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H8_Family)
[`HP-Focus`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_FOCUS)
[`HP-PA`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PA-RISC)
[`i860`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_i860)
[`IA-64`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-64)
[`IQ2000`](http://www.ic72.com/pdf_file/v/165699.pdf)
[`M32C`](https://www.renesas.com/en-eu/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/m16c.html)
[`M32R`](https://www.renesas.com/en-eu/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/m32r.html)
[`M68k`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_68000_series)
[`M88k`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_88000)
[`MCore`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C2%B7CORE)
[`Mico32`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LatticeMico32)
[`MicroBlaze`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroBlaze)
[`MIPS16` `MIPSeb` `MIPSel`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_instruction_set)
[`MMIX`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMIX)
[`MN10300`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MN103)
[`Moxie`](http://moxielogic.org/blog/)
[`MSP430`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_MSP430)
[`NDS32`](http://osdk.andestech.com/index.html)
[`NIOS-II`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nios_II)
[`OCaml`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCaml)
[`PDP-11`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11)
[`PIC10` `PIC16` `PIC18` `PIC24`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIC_microcontroller)
[`PPCeb` `PPCel`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC)
[`RISC-V`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC-V)
[`RL78`](https://www.renesas.com/en-eu/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/rl78.html)
[`ROMP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROMP)
[`RX`](https://www.renesas.com/en-eu/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/rx.html)
[`S-390`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/390_ES/9000_Enterprise_Systems_Architecture_ESA_family)
[`SPARC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARC)
[`STM8`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM8)
[`Stormy16`](https://sourceware.org/cgen/gen-doc/xstormy16.html)
[`SuperH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperH)
[`TILEPro`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TILEPro64)
[`TLCS-90`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toshiba_TLCS#90)
[`TMS320C2x` `TMS320C6x`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Instruments_TMS320)
[`V850`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V850)
[`VAX`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VAX)
[`Visium`](https://www.slideshare.net/AdaCore/controls-and-dataservices)
[`WE32000`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellmac_32)
[`X86-64`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)
[`X86`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86)
[`Xtensa`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensilica)
[`Z80`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zilog_Z80)
[`#6502#cc65`](https://github.com/cc65/cc65)